# MySQL Server Crash for unknown reason

Tags: dll, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Find below the MySQL log file.

```
150310 16:24:02 - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=371195904
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=9
max_threads=2000
threads_connected=9
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2939865 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

thd: 0x19fafcf0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
000007FEFCAA6244    mswsock.dll!???
000007FEFCAA615C    mswsock.dll!???
000007FEFCAA60FF    mswsock.dll!???
000007FEFCAB4C9E    mswsock.dll!WSPStartup()
000007FEFF74DE54    WS2_32.dll!setsockopt()
00000001403877A7    mysqld.exe!vio_timeout()[viosocket.c:410]
00000001400738CD    mysqld.exe!my_net_set_read_timeout()[net_serv.cc:1160]
0000000140099EE4    mysqld.exe!login_connection()[sql_connect.cc:962]
000000014009A067    mysqld.exe!handle_one_connection()[sql_connect.cc:1128]
000000014031F645    mysqld.exe!pthread_start()[my_winthread.c:85]
00000001402EA017    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstart()[thread.c:295]
00000001402EA0E5    mysqld.exe!_threadstart()[thread.c:275]
00000000773759ED    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
00000000774AC541    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort...
thd->query at 0000000000000000=(null)
thd->thread_id=70
thd->killed=NOT_KILLED
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150310 16:40:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150310 16:40:59 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
150310 16:40:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
```

Comment: What is the value of your [net_read_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout)?

Comment: @MikeNakis I need to collect the data from poduction . will update here soon

Comment: Have you tried innnodb_force_recovery??

Answer (score 0):

Check your system log to confirm this is not due to OOM.
check you mysql memory allocation (Global and per-thread).